# How to effective manage object in render function using react

Tags: reactjs, render

I have a date in string form like this: `2019-08-05T20:36:51.283Z`.

And for example, I want to render `new Date('2019-08-05T20:36:51.283Z').getDay()`.

My question is: 
Is effective to create object each for each render?

`render () { 
     return (
          <div>
              {new Date('2019-08-05T20:36:51.283Z').getDay()}
          </div>
     ) 
}`

Probably not, because I am creating a new object in each render is called.

What is the best way (effective) how to do it?

Can you provide some example, or memoize library for this?

Comment: An important factor in answering your question is does the date ever change? If it does not, you should just set this as a contant outside the entire class component then consume it in render.

Comment: The code snippet is too short to answer the question appropriately. Memoization is better done on a costly calculation. This is too small a calculation for that. 
But as adam said it does depend on if the date ever changes.

Comment: does the `Date ISO string` change at all? if not it could be outside your component, or maybe as a class property. If it does change, for example when you fetch data, you could calculate that once and store it in your component state state.

Comment: This date is changed on the application load - not in real time.